# Convert csv file to json object and save to file?

Tags: json, node.js, csv

I am using https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson to convert a csv file into json object but not sure how to create a js file from the output. Using the command

```
$ csvtojson ./mycsv.csv
```

I want to save the output into new file, how can I do that using command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ csvtojson ./mycsv.csv > converted.json
```

See the [docs](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson#convert-big-csv-file-with-command-line-tool).

Answer (score 0):

From the `help` section, it doesn't seem like `csvtojson` cli supports it. But you can always use `>` to output the command output to a file.

Example: `ls > dir_structure.txt`.